# How to receive sms with R?

Tags: r

it is possible to send sms messages with r [like this](https://analyticsprofile.com/business-analytics/send-sms-for-free-in-r-or-python/)

```r
library(httr)

AUTH_ID="MAMJJIMWxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
AUTH_TOKEN="YTVmMzc0ZTY2OThmZjJmYjxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
message<-"Hi.. How r u ??"
url="https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/MAMJJIMWU0NJK1MDZMNT/Message/"
POST(url,authenticate(AUTH_ID,AUTH_TOKEN),body=list(src="9191xxxxxxxxxxx",dst="91798xxxxxxxxxx",text=message))

AUTH_ID="MAMJJIMWxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
AUTH_TOKEN="YTVmMzc0ZTY2OThmZjJmYjxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
message<-"Hi.. How r u ??"
url="https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/MAMJJIMWU0NJK1MDZMNT/Message/"
POST(url,authenticate(AUTH_ID,AUTH_TOKEN),body=list(src="9191xxxxxxxxxxx",dst="91798xxxxxxxxxx",text=message))
```

But is there any way to receive sms messages?

Comment: If you can find a service that provides a number for incoming SMSs, and said service also provide an API to access them, then yes.

Comment: there is no way to connect the SIM card, directly with rstudio with rstudio connections? [there are several software that integrate with sms messages](https://www.gpswox.com/en/user-manual/faq/how-to-configure-gps-tracker) so I don't know how.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see why not. I've used the same method with Python a couple of times in the past for a project, and it worked out the same way. You could probably even do something similar with the Twitter API to automate posts etc.